# Getting inserted ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert data into the database. What I have here, it works but I need to get the ID of the data from what I have inserted. The ID will be used to store the name for the Reminder.

```
private void appBarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            ToDoList todolist = new ToDoList();
            todolist.Title = titleTBox.Text;
            todolist.Description = descriptionTBox.Text;

            //date was added later, datacontext is needed to regenerate
            //DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(textDateOutput.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(dateData.Value.ToString());
            todolist.Date = DateTime.Parse(dateData.Value.ToString());

            context.ToDoList.InsertOnSubmit(todolist);

            context.SubmitChanges();

            DateTime Date = rDate.Value.Value;
            TimeSpan Time = rTime.Value.Value.TimeOfDay;
            Date = Date.Date + Time;
            String Content = descriptionTBox.Text;
            String Title = titleTBox.Text;
                   // ID = get the ID from database of the inserted data.


            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cBox.IsChecked))
            {
                if (Date < DateTime.Now)
                    MessageBox.Show("Please do not enter datetime lower then the current datetime");
                else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
                    MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave the title empty");
                else
                {
                    //gets the info and call the function to send the parameter
                    RegisterScheduleIfNotExist( /* ID */, Title, Content, Date);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
            }
            else
                NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

RegisterScheduleIfNotExist method

```
private void RegisterScheduleIfNotExist(string name, string title, string content, DateTime time)
    {
        ScheduledAction currentReminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(name);
        if (currentReminder != null)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(currentReminder.Name);
        }

        var reminder = new Reminder(name)
        {
            BeginTime = time,
            Title = title,
            Content = content,
        };

        ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted you have an ID field in your `ToDoList` class, it will be populated after `SubmitChanges` with the value assigned.

You can get the id like so:

```
context.ToDoList.InsertOnSubmit(todolist);
context.SubmitChanges();
int id = todolist.Id; //or whatever your ID field is called on the class
```

**EDIT REGARDING COMMENT:**

Your `RegisterscheduleIfNOtExist()` method does not have a parameter field for `id`.

You should either add one (change the signature of the method to include `int id, string name, etc...`

**OR**

If the `name` parameter of the method *is* the id field, just change the `int id = todolist.Id` to `string id = todolist.Id.ToString()`.

Here is an example of the method being changed:

```
private void RegisterScheduleIfNotExist(int id, string name, string title, string content, DateTime time) 
{   
    ScheduledAction currentReminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(name);

    if (currentReminder != null)
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Remove(currentReminder.Name);
    }

    var reminder = new Reminder(name)
    {
        Id = id,  //Add the id field here to the reminder
        BeginTime = time,
        Title = title,
        Content = content,
    };

    ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
}
```

Comment: I did as what you stated. and replace the variable in this statement. RegisterScheduleIfNotExist(Id, Title, Content, Date); But there is an error stating that it has invalid argument (Local variable) int Id.

Comment: Impossible for me to debug without seeing the implementation of `RegisterScheduleIfNotExist()` - Likely you are assigning the type of `Id` wrong, or it does not exist in your `ToDoList` class.  Can you please post the `RegisterScheduleIfNotExist` implementation as well as your `ToDoList` class?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well now. Careless mistake. Thanks once again

Comment: No problem, please accept my answer if it worked for you!  (Click the green checkmark below the up/down vote buttons)